# Firefox not rendering size properly of lavarel/bootstrap

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, rendering

A very weird thing happened a couple of hours ago.  I am developing a new site - which is already live [Utopia Africa](https://www.utopia-africa.com) - using laravel & bootstrap.  I am normally using Firefox on my mac to view the local site.  Suddenly everything started to be rendered "big" by Firefox as for a cellphone but with text extremely big (see image below) and all logos/images at full size (although img-fluid).  The size of text and images do not change when resizing the window.  I tried everything like clearing cache, rebooting... However, the same local site is perfectly rendered on chrome, opera & safari. And once again, the same source file (I compared them) is rendered well on firefox when on the live server (as the above link shows).  I am pulling my hair off with this one... any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you zoomed Firefox by accident? Press CTRL + 0 to set the viewport zoom to 100% instead of 300% it is now on.

Firefox zoom option:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/font-size-and-zoom-increase-size-of-web-pages

Comment: I knew it was something very simple and stupid. Indeed.  You are a genius... thank you @Dave!  I had no idea that the zoom factor was saved for a domain even after deleting site data and rebooting the computer!